# Rewrite Vite Urls on dev server

Tags: vite

I am using Firebase, and my firebase.json file includes this:

```
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/spa/**",
        "destination": "/spa/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/exp/**",
        "destination": "/exp/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

In my vite.config.js, my config includes this:

```
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: 'index.html', 
        spa: '/spa/index.html', 
        exp: '/exp/index.html', 
      },
    },
  },
```

After the build is deployed to hosting, the any page that goes to `site.com/exp/***` rewrites properly to be handled by `exp/index.html`. However, it doesn't do the url rewrites until it is hosted.

How can I do the url rewrites on my development server?

Using: React, Firebase/Firestore, Vite.js, no SSR

Answer (score 0):

You could try to adjust `origin` and `base` options for the dev server, to match your build:

https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-origin

https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-base

also don't forget other URL related options like the shared `base`

https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base

Comment: I read all those pages, and I am not sure what exactly to do.